# JS; Convert a string to binary then to UNARY

Tags: javascript, string, binary

Here is exercice and example

> Binary with 0 and 1 is good, but binary with only 0, or almost, is
>   even better! Originally, this is a concept designed by Chuck Norris to
>   send so called unary messages.
>
> Write a program that takes an incoming message as input and displays
>   as output the message encoded using Chuck Norris’ method.
>
> #### Rules
>
> Here is the encoding principle:
>
> The input message consists of ASCII characters (7-bit) The encoded
>   output message consists of blocks of 0 A block is separated from
>   another block by a space Two consecutive blocks are used to produce a
>   series of same value bits (only 1 or 0 values):
>   - First block: it is always 0 or 00. If it is 0, then the series contains 1, if not, it contains 0
>   - Second block: the number of 0 in this block is the number of bits in the series     Example Let’s take a simple example with a message which
>   consists of only one character: Capital C. C in binary is represented
>   as 1000011, so with Chuck Norris’ technique this gives:
>
> ```
> 0 0 (the first series consists of only a single 1)
> 00 0000 (the second series consists of four 0)
> 0 00 (the third consists of two 1)
> So C is coded as: 0 0 00 0000 0 00
> ```
>
> Second example, we want to encode the message CC (i.e. the 14 bits
>   10000111000011) :
>
> ```
> 0 0 (one single 1)
> 00 0000 (four 0)
> 0 000 (three 1)
> 00 0000 (four 0)
> 0 00 (two 1)
> So CC is coded as: 0 0 00 0000 0 000 00 0000 0 00
> ```

I m stuck on the string "%";

```
const MESSAGE = "%";
let binaryMess="";
for(let i = 0; i<MESSAGE.length; i++){
    binaryMess += MESSAGE.charCodeAt(i).toString(2);
}
const regex = /(1*)(0*)/g;
const answer = binaryMess.replace(regex, (str, g1, g2)=>{
  let a="", b="";
  if(g1)a = "0 "+"0".repeat(g1.length);
  if(g2)b = "00 "+"0".repeat(g2.length);

  if(a&&b){return a + " " + b + " ";}
  else if(a){return a + " "}
  else if(b){return b + " "}
  else{return ""}
});



console.log(answer.trim());
```

The result =>
Failure
Found: 0 0 00 00 0 0 00 0 0 0
Expected: 00 0 0 0 00 00 0 0 00 0 0 0

Any idea why it s not working? I managed to do it with "c" "cc" but didn't with "%" and "Chuck Norris' keyboard has 2 keys: 0 and white space."

Comment: `.toString(2).padStart(7, "0");` would probably help, yet maybe not fix everything.

Comment: Well it worked thanks, I don't understand  padStart but I m going to look it up!

Comment: Well e.g. for a space, " ", the binary doesn't have seven digits - it's 0b100000. For an encoding like this (7 bit blocks), you always want full seven bits, 0100000. You need to "pad the start", if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.toString(2).padStart(7, "0"); would probably help, yet maybe not fix everything. – ASDFGerte